# Can I reset my stay in Korea by going out?

Tags: visas, south-korea

I live in a country which allows me to stay in Korea for 90 days on a tourist visa. I’m wondering is it enough for me to go out from Korea, let say I go to Japan for few days and then I go back to Korea. Would I be allowed to stay 90 more days in Korea then?